# Can "canActivate" received data?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

I have these lines in my router:

```
..
    canActivate: [MyGuard], 
    path: "search",
    component: SearchComponent,
    data: {
        accessRoles: [roleAdmin, roleUser]
    }
..
```

I want to limit access to SearchComponent by canActivate of MyGuard.

Is it possible to get this data array from canActivate?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  console.log(route.data)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. OMG I spent lots of time but the answer it so simple. Thank you very much!